# What is the meaning of Spirit ###?

Tags: military, usa, regulations, b-2

[This](https://www.popularmechanics.com/military/g1080/we-fly-a-b-2-stealth-bomber/) Popular Mechanics article writes (about the [B-2 Spirit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northrop_Grumman_B-2_Spirit)).

> Only 543 people have ever flown in the cockpit of a B-2. Upon landing I'll become number 544, with the new Air Force handle "Spirit 544."

1. Do people who have flown in B-2 Spirits have the Air Force handle "Spirit ###?"
2. If so, which regulation/directive/etc. specifies that the handle of people who have ever flown in the cockpit of a B-2 Spirit be "Spirit ###?"

Comment: @downvoter, Please comment or edit the question to improve it? Thanks!

Comment: I’m not voting to close as “too broad” since it’s a very specific question, but it leans pretty far toward useless *gee whiz* trivia, uninteresting to nearly everyone. I suspect that explains the downvotes. But I don’t think it’s worth closing.

Comment: @RalphJ I'm sorry you feel this way. This was definitely not my intention. I will promptly remove the *gee whiz* trivia portion. Also, I wasn't going to use this as trivia. I was genuinely curious.

Comment: @RalphJ Is the question better now? Or would you recommend deletion?

Comment: @all Any comments are appreciated.

Comment: I think you should rephrase the question title as "What is the meaning of Sprit ###?" and edit the detail of the question to indicate you think this is and then put your 2 subquestions.

Comment: @ManuH Thanks for the advice, I will do so.

Comment: I suspect the title was meant to refer to "Spirit", not "Sprit", since the former is what you're using in the question body. If I'm wrong, feel free to roll back the edit.

Comment: @aCVn Good catch, thanks!

Comment: US military aviators get to choose their own 'handles' (callsigns), like "Maverick" and "Goose", so presumably it's a tradition that B-2 aviators choose "Spirit ###" as their handle. It doesn't have to be a regulation.

Comment: @DJClayworth As I understand it, their *squadron mates* choose their callsign.

Comment: That US military pilots have a handle? Yes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spirit XXX (Number) and Callsigns are different.

Spirit Number is the order of having flown the B-2. This Covers Pilots and VIP, journalist or having been reward with this incentive flights.

```
eg.
Spirit 1: July 17, 1989: B. J. Hinds, Northrop’s chief B-2 test pilot,
Spirit 2: July 17, 1989: Col. R. S. Couch "Rick" USAF First Co-pilot
```

This is similar to the Bandit Number used for the F-117 (and maybe the SR-71)

The current number excess 760 now.

I am sure the B-21 will have a Raider number.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is there actually a list of that somewhere?

Comment: I have seen no (online) public list - I assume there has to be a list and curator of it!

Comment: Ok, that's disappointing. Thanks for your answer though.

Answer (score 3):

Taking your questions in order:

> Do people who have flown in B-2 Spirits have the Air Force handle "Spirit ###?"

**It's plausible**. The author of the article says so and there doesn't seem to be any reason to lie about such a trivial detail. That said, he also refers to the pilot as "Scar" rather than as "Spirit [whatever]" so even if Spirit-number is a callsign that a pilot has *earned*, it doesn't mean it's necessarily the one that they'll always fly with.

> If so, which regulation/directive/etc. specifies that the handle of people who have ever flown in the cockpit of a B-2 Spirit be "Spirit ###?"

**There seem to be no such regulations, or if any do exist, they are applied individually.** Pilot callsigns are generally given informally, according to [this article](https://slate.com/human-interest/2013/08/how-do-fighter-pilots-typically-earn-their-call-signs.html), which is not an official military publication. Although the content of [this article](https://www.military.com/daily-news/2018/11/07/female-airman-given-offensive-call-sign-during-drinking-event.html) is unfortunate, it substantiates the first one. Finally, the Air Force publishes [official voice call sign guidelines](https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a403713.pdf), which do not list regulations for pilot callsigns.

Comment: @BarryHarrison - Yes I do, but I also mean to indicate that particular group of pilots might have "rules" that are only applied within that group, such as "All our callsigns follow theme X" or "Nobody gets callsign Y in memory of pilot Y who died last year" and so on.

Comment: @BarryHarrison Sure, you could google "callsign traditions" or better, **ask it as a new question** here! One fairly standard rule is the bar test: your callsign will probably be embarrassing, but shouldn't be so embarrassing that you can't pick up dates at the bar with it.

Comment: I am reading [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_AC-130) right now and part of it reads: "...one AC-130H, AF Serial No. 69-6567, call-sign Spirit 03, opted to..." So I guess Spirit isn't a unique callsign?

Comment: @BarryHarrison - At this point the comment thread is becoming an extended discussion. You should ask a new question about this new topic, so you can get more answers than just mine.